# Need to return log in password

Tags: password, restore, logging

I removed the guest account and I only have an admin account, with an active password.

Couple of weeks ago I disabled password through "terminal" command line.
Today I want to return logging in with password, but when I activate this option in the settings, the start screen password is not asked by system.

How can I restore logging in to the system with a password?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings -->User Accounts, and make sure that Automatic Login is turned OFF

[image]

Choose Set a Password now under Action, and just fill out the password info.

[image]